# Display a specific dynamic sidebar widgets on a specific page

Tags: themes, pages, sidebar, page-template, templates

I have had a wordpress site handed off to me halfway through completion. It's been at least a year since I last used wordpress and there are a lot of things I'm finding different. The way I am used to displaying different content on different pages is to create page templates for each page that needs unique content.

I am trying to display a different sidebar on one particular page than on the rest of the site. What I would have done a year ago is make a page template for this page and make a new sidebar file and then include the sidebar file in the page template. I've found that this doesn't work. The main culprits I can see are `loop.php` & `loop-page.php`, which were non-existent in the stripped down theme that I would typically use when building a site long ago. However, it appears that whoever had their hands on this thing before me has copied the 'twenty ten' theme and made changes to it under a new name.

I've registered a new dynamic sidebar in the theme's `functions.php` and I can see it in the Widgets section of the Dashboard and add widgets to it.

I can't for the love of god get it to display on the page I want it to though. I've tried the following:

1.) Given the page a custom template `template_news.php` and placed the following where the sidebar should be called:

```
include ('sidebar-news.php');
```

The `sidebar-news.php` filed containing code I copied from `sidebar.php` with the "News" sidebar id that I listed in `functions.php`:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-news' ) ) : ?>

<div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
    <ul class="xoxo">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-news' ); ?>
    </ul>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

The page template is applied to the correct page.

2.) Gone into `page.php` and changed:

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

to:

```
<?php 

if(is_page('18')) {
   include ('sidebar-news.php');
}
else {              
   get_sidebar(); 
} ?>
```

I've also checked several times to make sure the page ID is correct and tried using the slug name instead but to no avail.

3.) Tried the previous in `loop-page.php`

4.) Placed the following conditional statement in `sidebar.php`:

```
<?php
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-news' ) && is_page('18') ) : ?>
    <div id="sidebarnews" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
    <ul class="xoxo">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-news' ); ?>
    </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Also after doing some research and finding out that the proper way to extend or change the functionality of a theme is to create a child theme, I attempted to do that, but it caused some things to break that I don't have the time to try and fix.

I've found that the default 'sidebar.php` is being called and displayed on the page, however, even though my conditional statement with the page ID is present, it's not displaying the custom sidebar widgets.

I also cannot seem to find how the default sidebar is being called on the page because removing `get_sidebar();` altogether on my custom template `template_news.php` , `page.php` , or `loop-page.php` doesn't seem to do anything.

Please can someone let me in on how to add this sidebar to the page.

Comment: Another Plugin is [**Widget Display Options**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-display-options/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you might need is simply to run `register_sidebar()` in an `'widgets_init'` hook. The TwentyTen theme has examples for `register_sidebar()` in its `functions.php` file, but here's what it might look like:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'twentyten_widgets_init' );
function twentyten_widgets_init() {
  register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'News Sidebar', 'yoursite' ),
    'id' => 'sidebar-news',
    'description' => __( 'The News Sidebar Area', 'yoursite' ),
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</li>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
  ));

  /*
   * THE REST OF THE SIDEBAR REGISTRATION CODE FROM twentyten_widgets_init() GOES HERE
   */
}
```

Also, in your `template_news.php` page template use the following code to call your sidebar which will load the `sidebar-news.php` file you created above:

```
<?php get_sidebar( 'news' ); ?>
```

You shouldn't need any of the other things you tried, and definitely not any `include` statements.

Comment: I have already done this. It was the first thing I tried exactly as you have laid out. However it does not work. The code in my custom template for the content and the sidebar are being overridden by default settings in `loop.php` & `loop-page.php`.

Comment: @jlego - Hmm. I tested my original with TwentyEleven and just retested with TwentyTen and it works. `loop.php` & `loop-page.php` don't have anything to do with sidebar generation, unless of course the other developer did some really screwy things. Can you update your question and post those two files as well as the content of your `template_news.php` file?

Comment: @jlego - Also, if you don't have [PhpStorm + Zend Debugger](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/tag/zend-debugger/) in your toolset, you might consider getting a copy. With it you could trace through your site line-by-line and see exactly why it is or is not working.

Comment: It was really frustrating me because I knew that this should work, and I had checked all the variables to make sure I had the template set correctly and didn't have any mistakes in my code. Turns out that whoever had their hands on it before me had gotten a blogroll to show up on the page by setting that particular page to the "posts" page in the wp admin. So when I went to make a custom template, that setting was overriding my template and telling the page to run the code in those files. Thanks for your help though. I will check out PHPStorm and Zend Debugger.

Comment: Even though this did not solve the specific issue I was having, This is the correct way to accomplish adding a sidebar to the page. I believe the actual solution to my issue was limited to my specific case, so I am marking your answer as the solution to this question in response to the number of views this question has.

Comment: @jlego - Wow, thanks for coming back to much later. Anyway, sorry I wasn't able to help you with your specific use-case.

Answer (score 1):

To display a widget only on specific pages where all your pages have the same sidebar, you may use one of those plugins :

[**Display Widgets**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/display-widgets/)

> Simply hide widgets on specified pages. Adds checkboxes to each widget to either show or hide it on every site page.

[**Widget Logic**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/)

> Widget Logic lets you control on which pages widgets appear using WP's conditional tags. It also adds a 'widget_content' filter.

Comment: Also a great plugin for this is https://wordpress.org/plugins/dynamic-widgets/